# ios - how to customize a UISwitch to have different wording and be displayed differently?

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I have a UISwitch I am working with on my storyboard, and I am having trouble changing the wording from on/off to private/public which is what I need for my app.  Also I would like the switch to be horizontal and longer so that a brief explanation can be added next to it.

Is that possible? How do I do that? I am attaching a screen shot of what I current[image]ly have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under iOS 5 you cannot customise UISwitch apart from tintColor.

If you want onImage and offImage customisation, you might want to wait to see what iOS 6 brings.

To switch between "Public" and "Private" as if using radio buttons, you should use a UISegmentedControl which can be customised as required.

Comment: thanks. What I really wanted to do it to have some sort of a radio-button type of switch.  What would you recommend I use?

Comment: Ah.  No iOS control for radio buttons currently exists but the nearest equivalent is UISegmentedControl which would allow you to switch between Public and Private.  This control is also highly customisable.  I would strongly recommend you use this.

Comment: yes I hered of that, but I do not see that control in the bottom right of my storyboard where the options are.  Would you know how I can add that control? Thanks! :)

Comment: It's the control that has the number 1 & 2 in it (top row, 3rd from the left in your image).  Drag it onto your view and double click the text to change it to Public and Private.  You can also use the Inspector to change other properties.  It's description is "Segmented Control"

Comment: ah I see. I just tried it and it is what I wanted. Do you know if it is possible to put it on two lines so that I can fit more words into the descriptions?

Comment: I don't believe so.  You may be able to alter the text size but I've never tried this.  Might be worth asking a new question to see if anyone knows differently.